# Stop refreshing listView on change in Database

Tags: android, listview, android-cursorloader

I am creating a **`ListView`** using **`cursorLoader`**. If any changes happen in Database, i don't want to refresh my list data or restart loader. Is there any solution?

Here is how i am loading my data from my database.

```
@Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int arg0, Bundle arg1) {

        String SELECTION = MyContactsQuery.SELECTION ;
            return new CursorLoader(SelectContactsForGroup.this, MyContactsProvider.CONTENT_URI, MyContactsQuery.PROJECTION,SELECTION, null, MyContactsQuery.SORT_ORDER);

    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> arg0, Cursor arg1) {
        if(arg1.getCount() <= 0){
            invitelist.setFastScrollAlwaysVisible(false);
        }else{
            invitelist.post(fitsOnScreen);
        }

        if(!isfromRestartLoader){
            arg1.moveToFirst();
            while(arg1.moveToNext()){
                checkedStates.put(arg1.getString(arg1.getColumnIndex(MyContactsConstants.CONTACT_JID)), false);
            }
            arg1.moveToFirst();
        }
        madapter.swapCursor(arg1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> arg0) {
        if (arg0.getId() == MyContactsQuery.QUERY_ID){
            madapter.swapCursor(null);
        }
    }
```

And in my onCreate method :

```
getLoaderManager().initLoader(MyContactsQuery.QUERY_ID, null, (LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>) this);
```

Comment: What information can you provide about `Database`?

Comment: M using content provider having a table of contacts.

Comment: can you post your code? may be you're setting a notification uri on your cursor..

Comment: you know `CursorLoader`s register a `ContentObserver` on the cursor they provide (you can check it's source code to see how they're doing it).. so if you don't want to receive updates try to implement your custom loader

Comment: Ok, i will definitely try this but i need a solution as soon as possible..Is there any other solution?

Comment: check the answer.. you can replace your `CursorLoader` with an `AsyncTaskLoader`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `CursorLoarder` registers a `ContentObserver` on the uri you can use another implementation of `Loader`

```
@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int arg0, Bundle arg1) {

    String SELECTION = MyContactsQuery.SELECTION ;
    return new AsyncTaskLoader<Cursor>(SelectContactsForGroup.this) {

        @Override
        public Cursor loadInBackground() {
            return getContentResolver().query(MyContactsProvider.CONTENT_URI, 
                                              MyContactsQuery.PROJECTION, 
                                              SELECTION, 
                                              null, 
                                              MyContactsQuery.SORT_ORDER);
        }
    };
}
```

this will return a cursor that doesn't have a notification uri and so it'll will not be notified when the db changes